# CreateProcess error=5, Access Denied

Tags: java

//edit: i dont lnow wh i did this that way, but it works with a jut inserting  y.toString() as path

:(

thanks anyway

if I try to execute a file and put the path as a variable, it does not work, I keep getting an "Access Denied" error. But when hard-code the exact same string the program starts fine

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

for(File x : files){
    File[] childfiles = x.listFiles();
    for (File y: childfiles){


    if(y.toString().endsWith(".exe")){

        String fstring ="\"\\\"";
        String lstring ="\\\"\"";

       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                fstring+y.toString().replace("\\","/")+lstring;
                p.waitFor();

    }
}
```

in i enter the filepath directly it works fine (and it looks EXACTLY) the same as the string i insert in exec

Comment: What is your code? Can you post a short, concise code example that reproduces your error?

Comment: Without some code, it will impossible to help. Are there blanks in the path toyou executable? Often are unquotet blanks the problem.

Comment: code added, sorry its a bit messy because ive beeing playign arounwith that a lot and just get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are executing "abc.exe".

According to `fstring+abc.exe+lstring` forms to `"\"abc.exe\""` and after replacing by `/` it is formed to `"/"abc.exe/""`. Which is wrong input to execution.

Directly execute `.exe` as :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(y.getName());
int responseCode = p.waitFor();
```